# SSL handshake aborted, when i am calling API in Jellybean

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, sslsocketfactory

I am working on a below 21 api level project and when i am calling an API then the error showing on jellybean that

> SSL handshake aborted

I try many methods but only one method is working on kitkat like:

```
try {
                SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(context.getApplicationContext());
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but this method is not working on Jellybean.
There are another error also showing that:

> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires
>   13400000 but found 9256030

Please suggest me best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")

Comment: Its not working, this issue is remain same, its working above API level 18 but not working on API level 18(Jellybean)

Comment: Can you please try from here solution given in this link https://medium.com/@krisnavneet/how-to-solve-sslhandshakeexception-in-android-ssl23-get-server-hello-tlsv1-alert-protocol-13b457c724ef  hope it will help you

Comment: This solution that he is given on medium is also working for above 18 API level, I just tried it

Comment: SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
SSLContext mySSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS" );
 mySSLContext.init( null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());

 OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .hostnameVerifier( myHostnameVerifier )
                    .sslSocketFactory( mySSLContext.getSocketFactory(), (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0])
                    .build();


HostnameVerifier myHostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                       String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                       String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }
    }};
```

Comment: implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'

Comment: working above 18 but not working in 18 API level. issue is remain same